# Getting this warning "#warning 64BIT: Check formatting arguments"

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm getting this warning "#warning 64BIT: Check formatting arguments" when upgrading my iOS app to the 64-bit architecture using Apple's 64-Bit conversion script.

Here's the code:

```
NSString *string;
NSInteger min=1;
string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld minutes",(long)min];
```

`min` was an `int`, which I changed to `NSInteger`.  I also then changed the format statement from `%i` to `%ld` and type casted `min` to `long`.

Warning appears right above the `string=` line.  This warning is showing up everywhere I changed an `int` to an `NSInteger`.

Comment: Your code works for me. Moreover, the syntax of the diagnostic is strange. Please add the complete error message from the build log. Add the version of Xcode.

Comment: The syntax came from Apple's 64-bit conversion script.  See answer below.  Thanks

Comment: *Apple's 64-bit conversion script* Well, not completely unimportant to know… Please, add it to your Q, so others can understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, the 64-bit conversion process adds this wherever it detects a format string being used. There should be an actual line in the code that begins with `#warning`. The warning is simply put there to alert you to double-check to make sure your formatting arguments are correct; once you've done this, you should be able to delete the `#warning` line from your source code and the warning should go away.

Comment: I forgot to mention specifically that I used the 64-bit conversion process that you mentioned.  I was able to delete the '#warning' lines and they did not come back when rebuilding.  Thanks